# Prove that there exists no polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 1 or 2 which divides $x^3-2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I assume I need to look at the ideal $\left<x^3-2\right>$, but I do not know how to proceed.

Hints only please!

Comment: If a deg 1 polynomial over the rationals is a divisor what does that imply w.r.t. the roots?
If a deg 2 polynomial is a divisor what can you say about the result of the division?

Comment: Suppose it is reducible, then it is divisible by a polynomial of degree one. But then it needs a a zero in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What can you say your polynomial has if a linear (i.e, degree 1) polynomial divides it? Moreover, what are the degrees of possible factors of your polynomial? How does this help answer your question?

Comment: By the way, $\langle$ and $\rangle$ (typed \langle and \rangle, respectively) are the symbols you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** [A famous irreducibility criterion is applicable here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)

Comment: You might all suggest [the other one, too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) since it is very pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another approach: If this polynomial was to factor, it would have to have a root in $\mathbb Q$.

If you can figure out why this is true, and then prove that the conclusion is false,  you’re done.

Answer (score 0):

Oooh, I love this question! It's always really fun showing things are irreducible! I'll try not to spoil all the fun!

Okay okay, so the goal is to prove $x^3-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Yes, I'm aware that's not what the question directly says, but it's what it's *indirectly saying*. Because, hypothetically, *if we could factor it*, we would have for some $f,g,h \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$:
$$x^3-2 = f(x)g(x)h(x)$$
where only these cases are possible:

- $\deg f = 2, \deg g=1,$ and $\deg h = 0$ (that is to say, $h \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ and is a "constant"), and
- $\deg f = \deg g = \deg h =1$.

So showing that nothing of degree $1$ or degree $2$ divides $x^3-2$ essentially shows it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$!

Alright, I'm going to have to spoil half of the problem because it's impossible not to -- it's just too straightforward. But don't worry, the other, more worthwhile one is all yours. For the degree $1$ case, let's assume that $x^3-2$ has a factor of degree $1$. If it has such a factor, then it must have a root, correct?

To elaborate in case you don't see why, note that if $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $1$ then it must be of the form
$$a_0+a_1x$$
for $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now *specifically because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field*, the element $a_1^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and more importantly we have $-a_1^{-1}a_0 = -\frac{a_0}{a_1} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore the polynomial $f(x)$ has a zero:
\begin{align*}
f\left(-\frac{a_0}{a_1}\right) &= a_0+a_1 \left( -\frac{a_0}{a_1} \right) \\
&= a_0+(-a_0) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

So now let's go back to the problem! As shown above, if $x^3-2$ had a factor of degree $1$, then it must have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$. That is, an $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ that satisfies $x^3-2=0$ but that $x$ would also have to satisfy
$$x^3=2$$
as well -- but hey! Wait a minute! $\sqrt[3]{2}$ clearly isn't in $\mathbb{Q}$! And that's the end of that.

Now the other part, showing now factors of degree $2$, follows *literally directly* from this. I'll lay it out one by one below in spoilers, but try it first!

**Assumption:**

> Assume $x^3-2$ has a factor of degree $2$. Let that be some polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$.

**First Implication:**

> We then have $f|(x^3-2) \implies x^3-2 = fg$, where $g \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$.

**Final Implications:**

> $\deg(x^3-2) = \deg(fg) \implies 3 = \deg f + \deg g \implies \deg g =1$, but we had shown that $x^3-2$ has no factors of degree $1$, thus this is a contradiction and $x^3-2$ has no factors of degree $2$ either.

Comment: To add on a little further given I'm now reading this over, perhaps it'd be a fun little exercise on the side to show (the obviously true) fact that $\sqrt[3]{2} \not\in \mathbb Q$.